# Python Class for Distances

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate the distance between 2 points using classes

```
import math

class Point:

    #This initializes our class and says that if x,y co-ords are not given then
    #the default is x=0, y=0
    def __init__(self,x=0,y=0):
        self.move(x,y)

    #move the point to a new location in 2D space
    def move(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y

    #reset the point back to the origin
    def reset(self):
         self.move(0,0)

    #This will find the distance between the 2 points
    def CalcDist(self,otherpoint):
        return math.sqrt((self.x-otherpoint.x)**2+(self.y-otherpoint.y)**2)
```

However when i try to print out the `CalcDist` it returns an error

```
>>> M=Point()
>>> M.reset()
>>> N=Point(5,2)
>>> M.move(1,1)
>>> print(CalcDist())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    print(CalcDist())
NameError: name 'CalcDist' is not defined
```

What am i doing wrong please?

Comment: Don't write comments on methods like that. Use docstrings: triple-quoted strings that are the first code *inside* the method itself.

Comment: @Amith Please don't make any nonsense edits like that any more. Whoever approved that should have their review privileges revoked.

Comment: BTW, Python has a built-in function in math module to get the hypot: "math.hypot(x, y)" Doc: http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#trigonometric-functions

Answer (score 3):

`CalcDist()` is a member method of `Point`, so you'd have to use: `M.CalcDist(N)`

Comment: actually M.CalcDist(N)

Comment: And - according to PEP-8 - should be `m.calc_dist(n)`.

Comment: @Matthias: that is right. But I used the API the OP was invented. Also PEP 8 entails guidelines and not strict rules.

Answer (score 0):

You should rewrite the last line as

```
print(M.CalcDist(N))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

class Point:

#This initializes our class and says that if x,y co-ords are not given then
#the default is x=0, y=0
   def __init__(self,x=0,y=0):
      self.move(x,y)

#move the point to a new location in 2D space
  def move(self,x,y):
      self.x=x
      self.y=y

#reset the point back to the origin
  def reset(self):
     self.move(0,0)

#This will find the distance between the 2 points
  def CalcDist(self,M,N):
     print(math.sqrt((M.x-N.x)**2+(M.y-N.y)**2))
```

**now in order to find distance.**

```
>>> M.reset()
>>> N=Point(5,2)
>>> M.move(1,1)
>>> x=Point() #creating new oject
>>> x.CalcDist(M,N)
```

This will print distance between 2 points.
For above points distance between 2 points will be 4.123105625617661

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).